# Disable dynamic brightness when that option is not available in Intel HD Graphics?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, intel-graphics

I can see the brightness gradually gets higher if I open a white window. In fact, the change is not very smooth, so that I can obviously feel the many gradual changes, which are annoying.

It was not like this before, but it suddenly started acting like this recently. I have updated the laptop to the latest BIOS and drivers.

I have searched the web, and this can be disabled in Intel's graphics settings. But I cannot find such an option. My IGPU is Intel HD Graphics 620. Is there any way to disable this without using Intel's Graphics settings like editing Windows Registry or something?

- Driver Version: 23.20.16.4849

---

I have checked the advanced power settings, and it had already been 'off'.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked under your advanced power settings in control panel? That is where it usually is.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it had already been disabled. I wonder why adaptive brightness still works.

Comment: This is probably a setting in your BIOS then. Can you add your make/model of laptop to your post?

Comment: I had checked the BIOS again just to make it sure, and there was no brightness setting. My laptop is a 2017 Samsung Laptop 9 series (which has many variants but they all look the same and I am quite sure they all share the same BIOS interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally called adaptive brightness, and it sometimes needs the manufacturer’s support to modify if it’s a setting built into the display firmware itself. For example, see this recent forum thread for the Dell XPS laptop, where Dell has published a firmware update to disable adaptive brightness on laptops with 4K screens, but not laptops with 1080p screens.

https://www.dell.com/community/General/Dell-XPS-13-9360-FHD-Adaptive-Brightness-Issue/td-p/5147488

Try looking through the BIOS settings, and try contacting your laptop’s manufacturer to see if they have released a custom firmware to disable adaptive brightness. You could also try downgrading your BIOS and drivers to older versions (the versions that worked before), but there could be security implications if the latest BIOS has security patches and new Intel microcode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My laptop is not an XPS, but a Samsung laptop, but it might have hard-coded adaptive brightness like the XPS. I could not find any brightness settings in the BIOS, which is very very simple. In that case, I would not want to downgrade the BIOS, as it may have security issues as you have stated. My only option would be buying a different laptop sooner or later, unfortunately.